# iOS Swift AVAudioSession - Changing Route to bluetooth explicitly

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avaudiosession

So I am in need of a requirement where I have to show, connected bluetooth device and play audio there, which currently I have done already. But say I want to switch from my bluetooth to Phones speaker, and connect back to bluetooth again after some point, can I do this? if not what would be my option to achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch routes, you will change the session's [options](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1771734-setcategory). For example, to switch from Bluetooth to the internal speaker, you'll want to remove the `.allowBluetoothA2DP` option and likely add the `.defaultToSpeaker` option. To move back to A2DP Bluetooth, you would reverse the options. (If you need HFP rather than A2DP, use `.allowBluetooth` rather than `.allowBluetoothA2DP`.)

Comment: Ok that sound about right, I was thinking of something like that, but was not confident, I will try tomorrow and will share my results.

Comment: So, it's kind of worked, but now an issue is, once I switch back to .defaultToSpeaker option, I miss the routeChange notification for any bluetooth device, basically it does not get called at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "for any bluetooth device?" Does the output actually change to another device, but you don't see a `.routeChangeNotification`?

Comment: For example, say I was on Speaker first, then I have put on my airpods, since have attached .routeChangeNotification, it will get to know that I have attached to AirPods. Now say I switched back to my Earpiece, where I removed all bluetooth options, it will pay there fine. Now say I have switched my another Bluetooth Speaker, so it will not catch that notification anymore, since I did not provided any .bluetooth option.

Comment: I think there's some confusion about what a route change here is. You're talking about when a new route becomes available, but the system does not route to it because you didn't allow it in your options? You're probably diving into UI that's not supported. Apple's way to specifically choose where audio is routed is MPVolumeView. If you're trying to do custom UI around choosing the precise route, that's likely going to not be possible. There is no `setPreferredOutput` on AVAudioSession. MPVolumeView will also deal with AirPlay, which I don't think you're considering currently.

Comment: Is there any issue MPVolumeView, because I tried it also and I can see, it lists all thing I need including all the bluetooth devices near me. Just one issue is, I cannot customise the UI, but functionality is important, unless theres some caveat, I would switch to it for now.

Comment: You've put your finger on it. Apple gives limited control over this UI. But it's the one they expect you to use. Best of luck.

Comment: So I have been using MPVolumeView, now I am facing some issues: 1. Sometimes it does not show Speaker and iPhone options. 2. When both options comes, if I choose speaker it changes to iPhone in the section options. I have used: audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do {
            try audioSession?.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: .allowBluetooth)
            try audioSession?.setActive(true)
            try audioSession?.overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to set audio session category: \(error)")
        }

Comment: For the use case you're describing, `.overrideOutputAudioPort` probably doesn't make sense to include.

Comment: I have removed it, but it does not have any impacts, biggest issue is I when I click on Speaker, it turns into iPhone, regardless of its playing over Speaker. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what "turns into iPhone" means here. You'll probably want a new question where you can post some screenshots of what does happen and what you want to happen.

Comment: Before click: https://ibb.co/r0wnGt9 After click: https://ibb.co/kqYFhCk

Comment: I recommend a new question with these put into the question, along with specific explanation of what code is used (in a way others can replicate), what is expected and why, and what happens instead. This is beyond what is useful in comments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76740619/ios-mpvolumeview-not-showing-speaker-and-iphone-options-always