# iOS - MPVolumeView not showing Speaker and iPhone options always

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, mpvolumeview

Currently I am working on an app, where I have to play some voicemail messages using Play button.So I have to employ MPVolumeView to let user to switch over different audio routes. Below is my code snippet how I am adding the view to my view controller:

```
 let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = false
    volumeView.tintColor = UIColor.gray
    
    for subview in volumeView.subviews {
        if let slider = subview as? UISlider {
            slider.isHidden = true
            slider.frame = CGRect.zero
            break
        }
    }
    
    if let airPlayButton = volumeView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIButton }) as? UIButton {
        //let customImage = UIImage(R.image.ic_airpods_bluetooth_dark)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        airPlayButton.setImage(R.image.ic_airpods_bluetooth_dark(), for: .normal)//airPlayButton.setImage(customImage, for: .normal)
        airPlayButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)

        _ = airPlayButton.imageView
           let symbolConfiguration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 40, weight: .regular)
           let sfSymbol = UIImage(systemName: "airplayvideo.circle.fill", withConfiguration: symbolConfiguration)
        
        airPlayButton.setImage(sfSymbol, for: .normal)
    }
    
    self.vwMV.addSubview(volumeView)
```

And here is how I am initiating the audio session:

```
 audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    
    do {
        try audioSession?.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: .allowBluetooth)
        try audioSession?.setActive(true)
        //try audioSession?.overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to set audio session category: \(error)")
    }
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(routeChangeEventHandle), name: AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Problem is, I am facing the 2 serious bugs with the above implementations:

1. I don't get Phones earpiece and Speaker options always
2. However, When I get both option, when I switch to Speaker options, the dialog shows me that as iPhone, after clicked. Please check the image below:

[image: Before choosing]

[image: After choosing]

Comment: Starting with the basics, does this work correctly if you use it as documented, without performing the unsupported manipulations to the view? In particular, things like setting the slider's frame to zero can have unexpected impacts on layout. Disabling the volume slider is built-in functionality (see `showsVolumeSlider`), so it's not quite clear why you're manipulating it. You should also compare this to what the Now Playing widget shows as routes (drag down from top to get control panel; you should see the Now Playing widget in the upper right with an AirPlay button).

Comment: Ok, I will check into that.